# Multiple ContextLoader* definitions exception when deploying web app as part of an EAR

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

Update 1: There might have been some residual files in my JBoss (not sure how though) cause it's working now.

I'm going for the [100% code-based approach to configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) for my Spring MVC web app. It works fine when I deploy it to Jetty. However, when I deploy it as part of an EAR, it complains about multiple ContextLoader* definitions in web.xml - which I don't even have...

My code:

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(WebConfig.class);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.acme.web.controller"}) //picks up TestController below.
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    //It's actually empty
}

public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testThisApp")
    public String testThisApp(){

        return "testThisApp";
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/app-web]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:264) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
```